# Is there a GREL OpenRefine function to identify and remove columns that do not contain any entries

Tags: openrefine, grel

I have a large project with many columns. Some columns have entries, but many columns do not have any entries. Is there a way of identifying which columns are completely empty and then removing these columns? Can this action be written in GREL to apply to the whole project in one go?

Currently using OpenRefine version 2.8

Comment: Hello. Short answer: no. According to your OS and your original filetype, you must use [some script](https://superuser.com/questions/750651/delete-empty-column-from-csv-file-with-bash-script) to clean up your extra columns before importing the file in OR.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify columns that have no values in them, but you can't remove those automatically.

In OpenRefine 2.8 you can create a Custom Text Facet on any column with the GREL:

```
filter(row.columnNames,cn,isBlank(cells[cn].value))
```

This will create a facet that lists each column with the count being the number of blank values in that column. If that count is the same as the number of rows in the project, there are only blank cells in that column

In OpenRefine 3.2 onwards the facet is directly available in the drop down menu on the "All" column

Unfortunately after identifying columns that contain only blank values your only option is to remove them using the usual mechanisms for removing columns in OpenRefine - there is no way to write a GREL that identifies the columns and removes them.